# print multiple PDF with cfinclude

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am trying to build a 'print all' feature so users can print all completed documents at once instead of one by one. I am trying to use cfinclude to iterate through all forms they need printed, but only one document renders ( the first one ). Here is the code I've tried.

```
<cfset URL.CFGRIDKEY = 5777 />
<cfinclude template="/note/sp_printform.cfm" />

<cfset URL.p = 160 />
<cfset URL.ref = 71 />   
<cfinclude template="path/to/pdf.cfm" />
```

Any way to make this possible with ColdFusion? Both included files are in the following format. I am trying to only use the previously created cfdocuments to avoid double the maintenance on the forms

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" >
    <cfdocumentsection>  
        <cfdocumentitem type="footer"> 
            <!--- footer content --->
        </cfdocumentitem>
        <!--- form content --->
    </cfdocumentsection>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: Rendering all the files in one browser tab is probably unachievable.  If the intent is to print all the pdf's, maybe the cfprint tag will help.

Comment: From the docs on `cfprint`: "Prints specified pages from a PDF file." Resse, a browser can only print one document at a time, so to provide this functionality, you'd have to merge the selected files, ordered, into a single PDF and then tell the browser to print that file.

Comment: CFPrint is for server side printing. If you mean client side printing, AFAIK it is not possible to print multiple files in a single pass with vanilla javascript. As Adrian mentioned, you must merge the content into a single document and render.  *RE: only one document renders* The cfdocument code is designed to output a single pdf to the browser. Using the tag multiple times will not merge output into one file. The headers and output of the first tag will be returned to the browser and displayed, and any other content ignored. So again, to display a *single* file, you must merge the content.